# Ruby modulus. Why are these two sums printing different answers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby and having problems with the %Modulus sums.

```
puts "example #{101 % 4}"
```

The above prints 1 in the terminal which is what I expected.

Why does the below print 101 in the terminal? Surely it's the same as above?

```
puts "example #{100 + 1 % 4}"
```

I understand that % is just another way of saying 'X divided by Y with J remaining". Therefore surely the 2nd example should also return 1?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses are important. Because of operator precedence rules, the second example is seen by ruby as

```
100 + (1 % 4)
```

Which gives

```
100 + 1
```

which equals 101

You probably meant

```
(100 + 1) % 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `%` has an higher precedence than `+`. So you could do something like

```
puts "example #{(100 + 1) % 4}"
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out it's to do with operator precedence, which you can control using parentheses `()` for example. The [rules](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) for Ruby are outlined in the official Ruby documentation as follows:

> From highest to lowest, this is the precedence table for ruby. High
>   precedence operations happen before low precedence operations.
>
> ```
> !, ~, unary +
>
> **
>
> unary -
>
> *, /, %
>
> +, -
>
> <<, >>
>
> &
>
> |, ^
>
> >, >=, <, <=
>
> <=>, ==, ===, !=, =~, !~
>
> &&
>
> ||
>
> .., ...
>
> ?, :
>
> modifier-rescue
>
> =, +=, -=, etc.
>
> defined?
>
> not
>
> or, and
>
> modifier-if, modifier-unless, modifier-while, modifier-until
>
> { } blocks
> ```

For a more general overview of order or precedence (outside the scope of programming) see the wikipedia entry [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

#### What happens if there's a tie?

It's worth noting that if there's a tie (i.e. two operators of the same precedence are in your calculation) then the operations are carried out from left to right.

Consider:

```
10 % 3 * 4
#=> 4 
10 * 3 % 4
#=> 2
```

or

```
10 * 10 / 2 * 4
#=> 200 
10 / 10 * 2 * 4
#=> 8
```